# Which hosting control panel to use?

Tags: hosting, isp

At the moment I'm using http://www.ispman.net/ as hosting control panel for a few debian linux servers. 
What I really like about this product is that it supports multiple servers and uses ldap as directory server. 
The problem is that it doesn't looks that future proof for a new setup, because the project seems almost dead.

Is there any other open source hosting control panel software, with an active community, that uses ldap and supports multiple servers (for debian lenny)?

Or is using directory servers for such tasks out?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried GNUPanel and Webmin?

IMHO Webmin is easy to setup, and highly modularized, while GNUPanel included some compoenents conflict with my current installed softwares.

Comment: Are you using virtualmin? Is virtualmin and webmin the same product?
Does any body tried this http://www.virtualmin.com/documentation/id,combining_virtualmin_and_ldap/